# Copy folders from remote location to local machine without Prompting for Password

Tags: linux, shell

```
ip:10.180.5.61
scp -r readonly@ip:/scratch/abcd/* /scratch/xyz
```

This command is prompting for password

The problem is that I want many folders to be copied from remote location to local machine

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you install your public ssh key on the remote machine. If your private key has no password, it will not prompt for additional authentication.

Comment: It is not that i want to copy only from one remote location. I want to copy from multiple remote location and also paste folders in some location

Comment: yes, but you need to add your public gpg key only once. From that moment on, `scp` will authenticate fully automatically without querying for a password, so you can put for instance `scp` in a loop...

Comment: But passwords for different remote location would be different

Comment: an ssh key is not a password: a password means symmetric encryption whereas ssh is assymetric encryption: you indeed first need to install your ssh key on all remote machines (and you will need to enter the password for all these remotes). Once done that, you well never have to authenticate with a password again since the public ssh key you've installed on all these remotes is linked with your private ssh key.

Comment: @RohanGala Maybe the `-i`option of `scp`can help. Look at my answer.

Comment: Sorry @CommuSoft but i don't have rights to install anything on remote machines.Most of them are readonly machines

Comment: I don't have any rights on the remote machine other than copying specific folders to my local machine

Comment: Can this help : http://serverfault.com/q/318474 ?

Comment: Maybe the best way forward is to talk to your sysadmin about being granted write access in your own home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a key pair and put the public key on the distant server. Read man ssh-keygen

Example:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key localFile user@remoteHost:/path/to/remoteFile
```

Alternative you could try pipe your password but be warned that it will show your password in your shell "history" too.

```
echo "password" | scp file user@host:/dir/to/copy/to
```

Comment: I know that by Copying  the public key to the remote server using ssh-copy-id user@remote_server  will add the public key to the authorized_keys file of the user on remote server and then able to copy without password,But my problem is that i don't have write access to remote server